# Missing value handling with imputation in a nested resampling procedure such that there is no information bleed from train to test

Tags: r, resampling, mlr3

I am looking through the documentation for the nested resampling procedure in the mlr3tuning package and I do not see any way that the package can handle NA values such that any information bleed between the training and hold-out sets is avoided, which would result in overly optimistic performance stats. I would ideally like a way to split my data in a nested resampling procedure such that:

full_data = N

train = N - holdout

test = holdout

Then I could perform an imputation on the train and test datasets separately and then run the model on train, predict on test and then select new holdouts and train from the full dataset, run the imputation on them separately and train, predict, repeat for the number of outer_loops.

Is there a way of doing this? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you're running the imputation separately on training and test, you're getting biased generalization performance estimates because you're using information in the test set for the imputation. For unbiased estimates, both model and imputation must be "trained" on the training set only and applied to the test set.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks for your response. If I train the imputation on the training set and then apply to the test set, and then train a model on the training set and then predict on the test set, will not the imputation performed on test, trained on train, be biased towards imputing values similar to train? And therefore will that not result in artificially inflated predictive power for my model, when predicting on test?

Comment: No, if you change the imputation for test sets that would be biased in the same way that creating a new model for a test set would be. Think of the imputation as part of the model (e.g. in an ML pipeline).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I see! So, within the context of a nested resampling procedure, is it fine run an imputation procedure on the complete dataset, and then perform the nest procedure as described? Or is there a better way in mlr3? Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you set up an ML pipeline that contains an imputation pipe operator, all of this will be taken care of automatically. See https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/pipelines.html#imputation-pipeopimpute

Comment: @LarsKotthoff This has been really helpful; thank you for your excellent response. Can you change your last comment to a response so I can give it a tick, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mlr3 handles all of this for you if you use pipelines (see the [relevant part of the mlr3 book](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/pipelines.html#imputation-pipeopimpute)). If you make imputation part of such a pipeline, it makes sure to train/test appropriately, just like for the model itself.

Briefly as an explanation, just like with the machine learning model you don't want to do any adjustments based on the test set; in particular you shouldn't impute based on test data. This will cause similar problems as doing this with a model, i.e. biased evaluation results that may not be representative of the true generalization error.

Comment: Could you support this? I understood that in mlr3, imputation is done separately to the train and to the test set. However, it should use the imputation 'rules' that were found on the train set and apply them to the test set. I am not sure which of the two mlr3 does.     The only information I found was here https://mlr-org.com/gallery/basic/2020-01-30-impute-missing-levels/index.html#resampling  and it is not very clear to me.

Comment: It does the latter -- imputation is "learned" on the training set and applied on the test set.